# How to increase the font size of 3 finger tap lookup results?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Is it possible it increase the font size when using lookup functionality after performing a three finger tap on a word?

Comment: I've tried changing the *standard text size* item in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Dictionary.plist` but this has no effect :(

Comment: See my asnwer..

Answer (score 3):

You can change it by modifying the `/Library/Dictionaries/YourDefaultDictionary/Contents/DefaultStyle.css` file.

You must change the part related to the **html.apple_client-panel**.

1. Open the file with TextEdit or any other editor.
2. Look for **html.apple_client-panel body**.

There you'll find this:

```
html.apple_client-panel body {
font-family:'Baskerville';
font-size: 14px;
```

This is the definition's font size.

If you want to change the size of all the fonts, you'll have to play around with the rest of the `html.apple_client-panel` related stuff.

When modifying the file, you'll be prompted to duplicate the document, as it is *protected*. Change it, save it, change (if necessary) its file format to **.css**, and just **replace** it inside the dictionary's package. This will require admin privileges, of course.

**Note:** Make sure you're editing the *DefaultStyle.css* file inside your defaults Dictionary package. Remember, too, to reopen the Application were you're testing this, or the changes won't be noticeable.

Comment: Please show us how to do this. ;)

Comment: I don't have ~/Library/Dictionaries directory.

Comment: Sorry, it is in `/Library/Dictionaries/`

Comment: I only have /Library/Dictionaries/New Oxford American Dictionary.dictionary/ and it doesn't have any files in it, only one dir named Contents.

Comment: Grrr... I got wrong the path. I'll edit it, again.

Comment: I tried to edit the file but I couldn't so I ran the following line in terminal sudo chmod 600 DefaultStyle.css but now I think I messed it up. What do you think?

Comment: Why couldn't you? You can just drag it to your Desktop, making a copy, and modify that one. Afterwards, just drop this copy into the original folder, authenticate, and click *Replace* when an alert prompts saying that another file with that name already exists.

Comment: OK, finally did it with sucess - however, I changed the number from 14 to 50, and it looks the same.

Comment: Did you reopen the application?

Comment: I use three finger gesture and the Dictionary app is closed.

Comment: Oh, and I didn't mention that the file you must change, is in the Dictionary you've got as default. I mean, if you usually use the *Thesaurus* changing the *New Oxford* won't do a thing. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: I meant the application where you are using the 3 finger gesture. If you have Safari opened, and change the file, unless you reopen Safari the changes won't be noticeable.

Comment: OK, I successfully made the changes, and it look really decent at 18 size. Do you have any idea how I can change Wiki font size? ( it's not in the dictionaries directory)

Comment: yeah, how to change font size for wiki now?

Comment: is there a way to fix size of the container? It won't fit now...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a way to do this automatically, I have tried within for example Safari to zoom in/out whilst the popup was present, and it ignores it, which makes sense as it's a system wide feature.  But I have found a possible alternative/workaround:

The best method for doing this is to enable the zoom functionality within *System Preferences*

The following screenshot shows my settings, and I have circled the changes from default that I had to make:

[image]

Now, if I want to zoom into anything on screen to make it larger, be it the lookup popup or anything else, I just center the mouse over what I want to look at, hold down <kbd>Control</kbd>, and scroll to adjust the zoom level.  I get a little rectangle which I can move around with the mouse/trackpad etc.  To get back to normal, just zoom back out fully.  The following screenshot shows the rectangle, but because of what I can only assume to be an odd screen drawing routine the zoomed content is not shown in the screenshot - rest assured that when you try this, the rectangle will show zoomed contents of whatever is currently underneath it.

[image]

Oddly, by accident, I also just discovered that pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> it immediately zooms into a preset level which I can then amend with my normal zoom approach (gesture, mousewheel, etc), but if you do not ammend the zoom then just letting go of the keys removes the zoon rectangle, so for a quick peak holding those 2 keys, then letting go is pretty quick.